# SwiftUI Picker: The padding of content in Picker does not work

Tags: swiftui, padding, picker

Is there anyway to "padding" content in the picker? Such as Text("...").padding().

```
Picker(selection: $picked) {
    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { num in
        Text("\(num)").tag("\(num)")
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .foregroundColor(pickedMinute == "\(num)" ? .blue : .black)
            .padding(20) //  ***It does not work***
    }
} label: {
    Text("picker")
}
```

Comment: I don't think padding will work. However, to pad horizontally, you can use spaces. See [Add space between name and image in Picker View in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77231077/20386264) and [How to make SwiftUI Picker take the whole free space in HStack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77114560/20386264)

Comment: In fact, I really need the padding on "vertical".  SwiftUI has some wired design( the principle is not unique, it confuses me a lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What *does* work is the `.font` modifier. And what also works is `.scaleEffect`. Used in combination, you can get a larger font with more spacing:

```swift
Picker(selection: $picked) {
    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { num in
        Text("\(num)").tag("\(num)")
            .font(.system(size: 15))
            .foregroundColor(pickedMinute == "\(num)" ? .blue : .black)
    }
} label: {
    Text("picker")
}
.pickerStyle(.wheel)
.scaleEffect(2)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: good share, BTW, how to make the selected background( the gray area)  width short( not scale too  much)

Comment: @nicholas.lcj Thanks for accepting the answer! To constrain the width, try `.frame(maxWidth: 100)`. This gets scaled too, so setting to 100 gives an actual width of 200.

Comment: yep, it's a solution. SwiftUI should give more opportunities to solve the "normal " issues  gracefully

Answer (score 0):

Picker in SwiftUI does not support padding,
you can create a custom Picker with padding like the following:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack {
        ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
            Text("\(number)")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(self.pickedNumber == number ? .blue : .black)
                .padding(20)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.pickedNumber = number
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like just Text in  ScrollView.  How to make the style  as  picker( .wheel) which belongs to picker